# Issue with std::set::insert using a custom comparator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, stdset

I wrote a small `struct` used to sort dependencies between projects (it could be used to sort anything really, the interface used is just a `std::string`) in a container/solution.

The dependencies are defined and fed from a json object (parsing is done using `boost::json`).

Example dependencies:

```
"container_dependency_tree": {
    "abc": ["def","hello","world"],
    "def": ["xyz","x","y"],
    "xyz": [],
},
```

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

namespace tmake {

    struct container_dependency_tree_t {
    private:

        std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>
            m_flat;

        bool
            m_compare(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const;//returns true if lhs depends on rhs

        std::set<std::string, decltype(&m_compare)>
            m_sorted = decltype(m_sorted)(&container_dependency_tree_t::m_compare);

    public:

        container_dependency_tree_t() {}

        container_dependency_tree_t(const boost::json::object& container_dependency_tree);

    public:

        const decltype(m_flat)&
            flat() const;

        const decltype(m_sorted)&
            sorted() const;
    };
}
```

Implementation:

```
#include <tmake/container_dependency_tree_t.h>

namespace tmake {

    container_dependency_tree_t::container_dependency_tree_t(const boost::json::object& container_dependency_tree) {
        for (const auto& kv : container_dependency_tree) {
            std::vector<std::string> dependencies;
            const boost::json::array& dd = kv.value().as_array();
            for (const auto& d : dd) {
                dependencies.push_back(d.as_string().c_str());
            }
            m_flat.emplace(kv.key(), dependencies);
        }

        for (const auto& f : m_flat) {
            m_sorted.insert(f.first);//***ISSUE HERE***
        }
    }

    bool container_dependency_tree_t::m_compare(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
        auto find = m_flat.find(lhs);
        if (find == m_flat.end())
            return false;

        for (const auto& dependency : find->second) {
            if (rhs == dependency || m_compare(dependency, rhs)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    const decltype(container_dependency_tree_t::m_flat)& container_dependency_tree_t::flat() const {
        return m_flat;
    }

    const decltype(container_dependency_tree_t::m_sorted)& container_dependency_tree_t::sorted() const {
        return m_sorted;
    }
}
```

The issue is with the instruction `m_sorted.insert(f.first);`.

I get thrown some compiler mumbo-jumbo that I dont understand - the error is somewhere within the STL implementation files (MSVC xutility(1372,19): error C2064: le terme ne correspond pas à une fonction qui prend 2 arguments).

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try making the comparator static, or a free function or a lambda. Currently it is a member function with an implicit first argument `this`, i.e. it takes three arguments, the first being your `container_dependency_tree_t`, the second `lhs` and the third `rhs`.

Comment: Ah good point! I just stopped reading after I encountered the first error :) You could probably devise something where you write the comparator as a lambda expression capturing this...

Comment: Or you can use `std::function`  and `std::bind()` but that probably would not have a benefit vs lambda. Btw I do not think your sorting criteria is valid but that would be separate question I guess.

Comment: How do I set a lambda as the compare operator ?

Comment: In your current design this is not easily possible: The template instantiation of `std::set` depends on the comparator type. The comparator type depends on the `container_dependency_tree_t`, because it must capture `this` or at least `m_flat`. The `container_dependency_tree_t` depends on the template instantioation of `std::set`. So you have a circular dependency problem.

Comment: @joergbrech then `std::function` should work and probably a feasible solution

Comment: Or, to avoid the runtime overhead of std::function and for better readibility (no decltype template parameters etc), you could use a private functor as comparator: https://godbolt.org/z/dWr9eGbda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from you trying to use a class member function which has an implicit first parameter that is the this pointer.  Since you need access to `m_flat` you need to wrap up the object to use with the function to call so that the `set` gets a function object that takes just two `const string&` parameters.  You can do that like

```
struct container_dependency_tree_t {
private:

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>
        m_flat;

    bool 
        m_compare(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const;//returns true if lhs depends on rhs

    std::set<std::string, std::function<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)>>
        m_sorted = decltype(m_sorted)([this](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
                   { 
                       return this->m_compare(lhs, rhs); 
                   });

public:

    container_dependency_tree_t() {}

    container_dependency_tree_t(const boost::json::object& container_dependency_tree);

public:

    const decltype(m_flat)&
        flat() const;

    const decltype(m_sorted)&
        sorted() const;
};
```